# 2nd Django form not rendering in HTML

Tags: django, django-forms

I can not figure out what is happening here. I have two forms but the second one will not render any input fields to the template. The second form is in a different template than the first. I am still very new to programming but I have searched everywhere for an answer to this with no luck.

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Name*'}))
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email*'}))
    contact_phone = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Phone Number*'}))
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your comments'})
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = ""
        self.fields['contact_email'].label = ""
        self.fields['contact_phone'].label = ""
        self.fields['content'].label = ""


class EstimateForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Name*'}))
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email*'}))
    contact_phone = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Phone Number*'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EstimateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = ""
        self.fields['contact_email'].label = ""
        self.fields['contact_phone'].label = ""
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.')
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
                , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
                , '')
            contact_phone = request.POST.get(
                'contact_phone'
                , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'contact_phone': contact_phone,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)
            send_mail('Email from your website', content, context['contact_email'],
                      ['email@gmail.com'],
                      fail_silently=False)

        return redirect('/contact')
    return render(request, 'main/contact.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })


def estimate(request):
    form_class = EstimateForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
                , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
                , '')
            contact_phone = request.POST.get(
                'contact_phone'
                , '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('estimate_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'contact_phone': contact_phone,
            })
            content = template.render(context)
            send_mail('Email from your website', content, context['contact_email'],
                      ['email@gmail.com'],
                      fail_silently=False)

        return redirect('main/index-v3.html')
    return render(request, 'main/index-v3.html', {
        'e_form': form_class,
    })
```

template

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="contact-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ e_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="thm-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is what gets rendered in the page

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="contact-form" style="margin-top: 25px" novalidate="novalidate">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="fsdSFKSDJDKFsdkfjJFKD">

   <button type="submit" class="thm-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass instance of form class instead of form class to template.

So change your code

```
return render(request, 'main/index-v3.html', {
    'e_form': form_class(),
})
```

Comment: Maybe I am not following. I need to pass an instance of EstimateForm class  to the template? Isn't the form_class variable doing that? I changed my code and still nothing.